# discount calculation not working in Products and cart page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, product, discounts

I have magento(v 1.9.2.4) site and I have to give 30% in every Products and its work on some Products and not work in some other Products.

[image]

now i'm edit any product detail(change name or price) then, it's work fine for that particular Product and show discount on that Product.
[image]

for solution i did Index Management but its not work.

**Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Comment: is ` cron is working in site` ?

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 : no.

Comment: if possible set up cron job from server side , also if you are not sure about cron, you can check by installing aoe scheduler extension

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 : i have **scheduler extension** and there is no cron.

Comment: i am not sure, that may be the reason...... click on `Apply rules` button once and check.....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 : i change 30 to 35% discount but its not change any thing but l'm edit any product detail than it show new 35% discount . any idea bout it

Comment: and i also did **clear cache** in **magento** and **Index Management** .

Comment: did you click on `apply rules` button as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX4eE.png) , also check your cron settings here : `System->configuration->system->cron`.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 : yes. : http://prntscr.com/ef16xl

Comment: check this [link](http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-being-applied-after-product-save-magento-ce-1-8-0-0/)

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 : its look like my problem has been resolved, but i need more test, thanks for help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you may need to check with `Catalog Price Rules`

Try click on `Apply Rules` button , also you need to have proper configuration in `System->configuration->system->cron` and follow [this link](http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-being-applied-after-product-save-magento-ce-1-8-0-0/)

you have definition of observer for `catalog_product_save_commit_after` event to apply all rules to product after product has been saved:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml -->

<config>

    <!-- Other code -->

    <adminhtml>

        <!-- Other code -->

        <events>

            <!-- Other code -->

            <catalog_product_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <catalogrule>
                        <class>catalogrule/observer</class>
                        <method>applyAllRulesOnProduct</method>
                    </catalogrule>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_commit_after>

            <!-- Other code -->

        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: can you help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573145/catalog-price-rules-apply-rules-programmatically

Comment: sorry i have no idea, you may get solution soon if you post here : http://magento.stackexchange.com